# Adding a return variable to a Number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, variables, math, numbers

I need to add the OptionPricing variable to the 2: 258 which is in the var AccompPricing, in this script. I want to write something like this 2: 258 + (var Price), but it doesn't work like that. The total package should be added to the second choices value. Example: 258 + The price the package = Total #2.

```
// Collect Data & Prices To Update Dynamic Prices

var OptionPricing = {

'pack11049': 1049,
'pack21199': 1199,
'pack31199': 1199,
'pack41299': 1299,
'pack51449': 1449,
'pack61499': 1499,
'pack71549': 1549,
'pack81699': 1699,
'pack91799': 1799,
'pack101999': 1999,
'pack112499': 2499,
'pack122549': 2549


};


function checkOptions() {

var Price = 0;

for (Packs in OptionPricing) {

    if ($('#' + Packs).is(':checked')) {           
        Price += OptionPricing[Packs];
    }
}

return Price;
}
var AccompPricing = {
0: 0,
1: 129,
2: 258 + (var Price),
3: 1057,
4: 1856    
};

function checkAccomp() {

var Accomp = parseInt($('#howmany').val(), 10);

return AccompPricing[Accomp];
}

function updateTotal() {

var ThePrice = checkOptions() + checkAccomp();


$('#TotalPrice').text('$' + ThePrice + '.00');

}

$(function () { $('.DoPricing').click(updateTotal); });
```

Comment: It's really hard to tell what you're trying to do. **When** do you want to add `Price` to `AccompPricing[2]`? Because `updateTotal` already basically does that. It gets the price back from `checkOptions` and adds it to the amount from the appropriate index of `AccompPricing`. So just removing the `+ var Price` from the `AccompPricing` object initializer would seem sufficient. So it's really not clear why you think you want something there, or what you're trying to do.

Comment: Well Here is what I am trying to accomplish. The OptionsPricing holds the final value of our radio buttons called PACKAGES. The AccompPricing holds an additional value and we will call that OCCUPANCY PRICE. But only for the 2nd Occupant #2 (2:258) $258 we want to charge them the full price of the package also, but not for #3 or #4. #1 is already getting charged the full package but we need to add the full price again IF there is a second occupant! Make Sense?

Comment: Not really, no. :-) So you want to do something with the result of `checkOptions` based on which entry in `AccompPricing` gets used?

Comment: I just want to add the final result of OptionsPricing to the #2 option in AccompPricing so the pricing will change. 258 + whatever the final result of OptionsPricing (packages). That way #2 gets charged $258 plus for example $1099 = $1357. But the $1099 will change on selection!

Comment: $1099 may be $2499 or $1999 etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you need a flag on the entries in your `AccompPricing` object to tell you whether you add the package price on again. *Something* like this: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/afocim/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/afocim/1/edit)

```
// Collect Data & Prices To Update Dynamic Prices

var OptionPricing = {

    'pack11049': 1049,
    'pack21199': 1199,
    'pack31199': 1199,
    'pack41299': 1299,
    'pack51449': 1449,
    'pack61499': 1499,
    'pack71549': 1549,
    'pack81699': 1699,
    'pack91799': 1799,
    'pack101999': 1999,
    'pack112499': 2499,
    'pack122549': 2549
};

var AccompPricing = {
    0: {Price: 0,     Flag: false},
    1: {Price: 129,   Flag: false},
    2: {Price: 258,   Flag: true},
    3: {Price: 1057,  Flag: false},
    4: {Price: 1856,  Flag: false}
};

function checkOptions() {

    var Price = 0;

    for (Packs in OptionPricing) {

        if ($('#' + Packs).is(':checked')) {           
            Price += OptionPricing[Packs];
        }
    }

    return Price;
}

function checkAccomp() {

    var Accomp = parseInt($('#howmany').val(), 10);

    return AccompPricing[Accomp];
}

function updateTotal() {

    var PackagePrice, Accomp, ThePrice;

    PackagePrice = checkOptions();
    Accomp = checkAccomp();
    ThePrice = PackagePrice + Accomp.Price;
    if (Accomp.Flag) {
        ThePrice += PackagePrice;
    }

    $('#TotalPrice').text('$' + ThePrice + '.00');
}

$(function () { $('.DoPricing').click(updateTotal); });
```

---

Side note: I've tried to use your capitalization style in the above. FYI, it's **very** unusual to use initially-capped variable names in JavaScript for anything but globals.

Comment: I tried to copy and paste the var AccompPricing you have and replace with mine and it doesn't give a total. Hmm?

Comment: @PhilMulkins: You can't just grab part of the solution and expect it to work. How you use the entries in `AccompPricing` changes too.

Comment: It looks like something that could work, but it just doesn't give a total. #2 needs charged double of OptionsPricing so you are right there but doesn't output a total.

Comment: You are right T.J., my bad. But it still doesn't work. Is there anything else I need to do to the HTML?

Comment: I'm a terrible javascripter Btw! But I am pretty good at PHP. I should have learned javascript first thats for sure.

Comment: @PhilMulkins: I had a typo in the `AccompPricing` object. Fixed.

Comment: Copied entire script, still says $0.00 after selection. I appreciate you helping with this. This is like the last problem I need to figure out.

Comment: @PhilMulkins: I had *another* typo in the `AccompPricing` object! (Hadn't had my coffee.) Fixed, and this time I created a live copy to make sure I'd run out of typos. :-)

Comment: That worked! You are a Javascript Rock Star!! LOL! Thank you so much!

Comment: You were very helpful! I went ahead and set the #3 and #4 to true that way it will always charge the double occupancy for #2. Before it would only charge if I made #2 selection. That worked like a charm! Very easy to understand. Thanks again!